# Why I can't translate image in the view by QGraphicsView.translate

Tags: pyqt5

I want implement an image view by PyQT5 using QGraphicsView. And I don't want scoll bars; and  I want to pan the image freely. That means I can pan the image outsize the viewport. So I make the scene with big range. Below is my code. I found that I can't translate the image by calling self.translate. I can't figure out why, please help:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QPointF, QRectF, QSizeF, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap, QTransform, QPainter, QCursor, QMouseEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QScrollBar
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import math
from PyQt5 import QtGui

class ImageViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ImageViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.setSceneRect(-10000, -10000, 30000, 30000)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.pixel_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.scene().addItem(self.pixel_item)
        self._last_pos = None

    def wheelEvent(self, event: QtGui.QWheelEvent) -> None:
        pass

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        self._last_pos = event.pos() 

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if self._last_pos is not None and event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            diff = event.pos() - self._last_pos
            print('translate: ', diff.x(), diff.y())
            self.translate(diff.x(), diff.y())

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        self._last_pos = None

   
    def loadImage(self, imagePath):
        pixmap = QPixmap(imagePath)
        self.pixel_item.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.pixel_item.update()
        self.centerOn(self.pixel_item)
        # self.setSceneRect(item.boundingRect())

  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    print("window size", window.size())
    image_viewer = ImageViewer(window)
   
    image_viewer.loadImage('4649---1.jpg')
    print('setting widge')
    window.setCentralWidget(image_viewer)
    # window.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And My goal is to implement a image viewer class that I can pan and zoom the image freely without scene limit. And I can call translate of scale method to adjust the image without mouse event to simultanously pan and zoom multiple ImageView to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason of your problem is explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#details):

> QGraphicsView keeps the center of the view fixed during a transformation. Because of the scene alignment (setAligment()), translating the view will have no visual impact.

The `translate()` function is used for complex transformations and does not affect the visual area of the scene.

The reality is that, if you use a large enough scene rect (as you are doing), you should not implement mouse events at all, since using the `ScrollHandDrag` will be sufficient: remove **all** mouse event handlers and it will work as expected.

As an alternative, you could control the view box by translating the view's `sceneRect` instead, but since the translation is incremental, you must always update the `_last_pos` to the new event pos, and the original scene rect must be as small as possible: the fact that the scroll bars are hidden does **not** mean that their behavior is ignored, so if you make the window smaller than the actual scene contents, they would actually control the viewport scrolling; making the view's scene rect extremely small will override their behavior completely.

Finally, in order to properly center the item within the "small" scene rect, you have to set its position to the negative center of its bounding rect.

```py
class ImageViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ImageViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1, 1)
        # ...

    # ...

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if self._last_pos is not None and event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            diff = event.pos() - self._last_pos
            self.setSceneRect(self.sceneRect().translated(-diff))
            self._last_pos = event.pos()

    # ...

    def loadImage(self, imagePath):
        pixmap = QPixmap(imagePath)
        self.pixel_item.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.pixel_item.setPos(-self.pixel_item.boundingRect().center())
```